# How would you get the resulting list of variable names from step()?

Tags: r

I'm working with the step() function in r. What is the way to get the list of variables that step() concludes should be kept in the model? Say I have a data frame with a response vector and several predictors X, Y, and Z. Step() concludes that only X and Y should be included in the final model. How do I get a vector `c('X','Y')`?

--

In response to the first answer, I've tried both $coefficients and names(). Neither works.

Here is the output from `print("names"); print(names(df_lm_2$coefficients))`

```
[1] "(Intercept)"                  "How.often2"                   "How.often5"                  
 [4] "How.often6"                   "How.often7"                   "How.often8"                  
 [7] "Bathroom.s.2"                 "Bathroom.s.3"                 "Bathroom.s.5"                
[10] "Bathroom.s.7"                 "Other.details..option.2.TRUE" "description_length"          
[13] "has_descriptionTrue"          "Other.details..option.6.TRUE" "Bedroom.s.2"                 
[16] "Bedroom.s.3"                  "Bedroom.s.4"                  "Bedroom.s.5"                 
[19] "Bedroom.s.6"                  "weekend1"                     "Other.details..option.7.TRUE"
[22] "Other.details..option.3.TRUE"
```

What I ultimately want is only the significant column names, not the levels of each factor. For context, here are the column names:

```
[1] "=------Colnames--------"
 [1] "Bathroom.s."              "Bedroom.s."               "bid_price"                "description_length"      
 [5] "has_description"          "hour_of_day"              "How.often"                "log_bid_price"           
 [9] "month"                    "Other.details..option.1." "Other.details..option.2." "Other.details..option.3."
[13] "Other.details..option.4." "Other.details..option.5." "Other.details..option.6." "Other.details..option.7."
[17] "req_source"               "Square.feet"              "Type.of.home"             "weekend"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the example in the help page of `?step`,

```
lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
slm1 <- step(lm1)
```

you can do this:

```
names(slm1$coefficients)
```

Look at `names(slm1)` for more enlightenment.